# How to properly create custom validation with react-reactive-forms

Tags: angular, reactjs

I wanted to create custom validation for my input forms by using react-reactive-forms. So, to achieve that I created this code:

```
form = FormBuilder.group({
        currentPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
        newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RESET_PASSWORD_FORMAT)]],
        confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, this.validateAreEqual]],
    });

private validateAreEqual(fieldControl: FormControl) {
    return fieldControl.value === fieldControl.get('newPassword').value
        ? null
        : fieldControl.setErrors(NO_MATCH_ERROR);
}
```

What I wanted to achieve is that if confirm password is not equal to new password then this error **NO_MATCH_ERROR** should be shown. But now I get an error "Cannot read property 'value' of null". I really need your help

Here is the photo:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please create a working example reproducing your issue?? You can form this sample react-reactive-for link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-reactive-form-sync-async-validation-47o7v

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, hi  Maniraj, I am sure that I get an error due to fieldControl: FormControl being null. Should I pass an argument to the validateAreEqual?

Comment: Can you show the data that you receive in ```fieldControl``` by doing ```console.log(fieldControl)``` inside ```validateAreEqual``` function ??

Comment: Maybe try to check if `fieldControl` and `fieldControl.get('newPassword')` exists before getting those values?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, I have added the photos. Pls check it out))

Comment: @Mir, I have asked for ```fieldControl``` value alone, unless you show that first, it would not be easy to identify the problem..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, but I have showed you exactly what I get concerning fieldControl, here is what I did private validateAreEqual(fieldControl: FormControl) {
        return fieldControl.value === fieldControl.get('newPassword').value
            ? null
            : console.log(fieldControl);
    } in the photos is what I got))

Comment: @Mir, Also take a look into this example it has exactly what you want https://codesandbox.io/s/react-reactive-form-user-register-3ku07

Comment: @Mir, I have not asked to make console inside else part.. Just do simple console inside first line of function and don't show the error message screenshot instead show the real data you are receiving.. You are getting error for value as null but do the console of ```fieldControl``` before executing any expression..

Answer (score 0):

Try below way

```
form = FormBuilder.group({
    currentPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
    newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RESET_PASSWORD_FORMAT)]],
    confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required],
}, {validators: [validateAreEqual]});

validateAreEqual(group: FormGroup) {
 if(group.get('confirmPassword').value == group.get('newPassword').value) {
    return { validateAreEqual: true };
} else {
   return null; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work.

```
form = FormBuilder.group({
    currentPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
    newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RESET_PASSWORD_FORMAT)]],
    confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required],
}, {validators: [validateAreEqual]});

validateAreEqual(group: FormGroup) {
    group.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({validateAreEqual: !(group.get('confirmPassword').value === group.get('newPassword').value)});
return;          
}
```

Comment: Could you make more detailed explanation why it should work?

Comment: @Terminat this will set the validation for confirm field based on the fulfillment of condition. However, the form status will be invalid.